# Handling transaction errors without using a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, transactions, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to write a template for building my database. I want the template to wrap all commands in a transaction so it can be automatically rolled back if anything fails.

Currently, I'm using a stored procedure containing this general structure:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;

    -- Commands here

COMMIT;
```

However there are some issues with this, for example it's impossible to add other stored procedures from a stored procedure. So I would like to have a similar functionality without being wrapped in a stored procedure. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find any way to catch SQL exceptions outside a stored procedure and without that I can't automatically rollback on error.

I've also tried something like this with the hopes that on an error execution should crash out of the first section without committing and then continuing on the next section with the rollback. But that doesn't seem to work:

```
DELIMITER //

START TRANSACTION;

    -- Commands here

COMMIT//

ROLLBACK//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION` returns 8.0.15

Comment: If I execute two commands in the transaction, where the second is set to fail (adding the same value again to a unique column in my test case) the result from the first command still remains after the script finishes. I would expect everything to rollback. Calling `ROLLBACK` manually after the script has finished works though and will remove the result of the first command.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as error handler is defined for compound statements which are only available for events, triggers and sps according to [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: I understand. For someone coming from C++, SQL sure is a limiting language :p